# I want to use variables in Form2 which I have declared in Form1

Tags: vb.net, forms, variables

This is my form 1

```
Public Class Form1
Dim excelapp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim excelwb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
Dim excelws As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Calling form for New
    Dim new1 As New Form2
    new1.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    'To Open File
    Using FileDialog As New OpenFileDialog
        FileDialog.Title = "Select your Excel file"
        FileDialog.Filter = "Microsoft Excel|*.xl*|All Files|*.*"
        FileDialog.ShowDialog()
        Process.Start(FileDialog.FileName)
        Dim s As String = FileDialog.FileName
        excelwb = excelapp.Workbooks.Open(FileDialog.FileName)
        excelws = excelwb.Worksheets(1)


        'End Using

        ' Using FileProcess As Process = Process.Start(FileDialog.FileName)

    End Using

    'Calling form for Open

    Dim new1 As New Form2
    new1.Show()
```

This is my Form 2

```
       Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'New Entry in existing excel file
    excelws.Cells(3, 1).Value = TextBox1.Text
    excelws.Cells(3, 2).Value = TextBox2.Text
    excelws.Save()
End Sub
```

I want to use all the variables and all the things from form1 in form2.
Please help me how to use those things in my form2.
Im preparing an application for taking user input and generate a pdf for it.
im using Excel to save the data and VB Express 2010 for creating the forms.
Please guide me :) Thank you very much.

Comment: Declare them as PUBLIC outside the functions/subs.

Comment: Can you help me with the code ? I'm kinda new. And If i declare them public, how should I mention it in form2 about those public data?

Comment: I dont see any variables in the first form; declared, "mentioned" or otherwise

Comment: `Dim s As String = FileDialog.FileName`
I want to use this **s** in my form2. How can I do it ?

Comment: Do you want to use `s`, or just `excelws` etc?  And is the `Textbox1.Text` from form1 or form2?

Comment: Yes I wanna use excelws in form2
And textbox1.text is present in both the forms, Im new to VB so my naming conventions are really poor, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: You need to declare them as public in a standard module, forms can't handle public variables.

Comment: Ok @Sgdva, So now I created a module in my project, how should I use it in my form ? 
For instance
`Public excelapp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application`

    `Public excelwb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook`
    `Public excelws As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet`
This is my module
I wanna use these in my form

Comment: @WesGourh You don't use the module itself, declare the variables there as public and then they will be available for other objects -such as forms, sheets thisworkbook-. OT: Nevermind, at first, it stated excel VBA, I'm not quite sure if you follow the same logic for public variables in VB itself.

Comment: I got confused by the excel-vba tag as well - I **think** my answer is still applicable in VB.Net, but I don't have any way of testing it.

Comment: @YowE3K your code would work in VB.NET. It's probably best to use a Module however so that once initialised they can be used anywhere within the project without the need to reference the form or worry that the form is disposed.

Answer (score 1):

Change your declarations of `excelws`, etc in Form 1 to be `Public`:

```
Public excelapp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Public excelwb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
Public excelws As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
```

Then, assuming your Form1 is still called `UserForm1`, you can change your Form 2 code as follows:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'New Entry in existing excel file
    UserForm1.excelws.Cells(3, 1).Value = TextBox1.Text
    UserForm1.excelws.Cells(3, 2).Value = TextBox2.Text
    UserForm1.excelws.Save()
End Sub
```

If it isn't called `UserForm1`, just substitute the appropriate name.